# CGAL How to save std::vector<Point> points into .xyz file?

Tags: c++, vector, cgal, std-pair

I'm new to C++ and I'm not familiar with vector and pair. I'm working on CGAL, and I want to save `std::vector<Point> points` into a `.xyz` file, but the provided example in CGAL doc uses different type `std::pair<Point, Vector>` in order to save. Could anyone please give me some clues?

I refer to [this example [link]](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_processing_3/Point_set_processing_3_2remove_outliers_example_8cpp-example.html) and I want to save after remove the outliers.

This is [the example [link]](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_processing_3/Point_set_processing_3_2read_write_xyz_point_set_example_8cpp-example.html) of read and write in CGAL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poor me! I've just read the [write_xyz_points.h](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Point_set_processing_3/include/CGAL/IO/write_xyz_points.h). The function has already been created.